# Detect if List if Changes after Filter - Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, list-manipulation

I need to detect if a list changes after using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Currently, I use the below code:

```
var bullets2 = bullets.filter((bullet) => {
    return (bullet[0] < 450)
})
if (bullets2.length != bullets.length) {
    bullets = bullets2
    update_user_pos()
}
bullets = bullets2
```

But this doesn't seem very effient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What doesn't seem efficient to you? Are you seeing a performance issue?

Comment: Why do you still do `bullets = bullets2` afterwards, even if the list didn't change?

Comment: @Bergi, good catch.

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau i'm making a game, and I'd like to make it as efficient as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that is the most efficient way, though [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101215/detect-if-list-if-changes-after-filter-javascript#comment118607658_67101215) pointed out that I could removed the end `bullets = bullets2`.

New Code:

```js
var bullets2 = bullets.filter((bullet) => {
    return (bullet[0] < 450)
})
if (bullets2.length != bullets.length) {
    bullets = bullets2
    update_user_pos()
}
```